# nested svg with cross domain support and fill attribute

Tags: reactjs, svg

```
<svg>
  <use xlinkHref={`${IconSet[iconName]}#${iconName}`} fillRule="evenodd" fill="#9e9e9e" />
</svg>
```

I am looking for a solution where I could embed an svg inside another svg loaded from a different domain.

But the various solutions I tried out include using `<use>` which fails because of CORS issue, and I tried  using `<image>` tag, but that wouldn't allow me to use *fillRule* and other attributes like those and also for some reason it just didn't render at all on screen. Just to put it out there I am on a React setup, not that it should make any difference.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: So I assume you are unable to fix your CORS issues due to not being able to change the server settings? You could use JS but that too will have it's challenges

Comment: @Dominik well the thing is I am developing a widget which will be used on different sites including shopify stores, but the icons and all that which will be embedded will be served from my own domain, hence I can't think of a CORS solution.

Comment: If you serve that from your own domain why don't you fix CORS then?

Comment: Sorry serve what from my own domain? even though the widget code is on my domain, its executed on shopify stores and it requests for icons from my domain and that use tag complains of CORS, but from what I understand its a limitation of <use> tag.

Comment: "For security reasons, browsers may apply the same-origin policy on use elements and may refuse to load a cross-origin URL in the href attribute. There is currently no defined way to set a cross-origin policy for use elements." Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use

Comment: Yeah no `use` is not going to work here but that's not a CORS issue but a browser limitation as you rightly pointed out. The only thing to do then is to use JS to embed the SVG into your DOM and then use it that way.

Comment: @Dominik Sorry that I mislead you saying that it was a CORS issue. So you are suggesting me to load the svg file with fetch and insert into DOM, and then use the `<use>` tag to load it? That makes sense theoretically